# ACSII World map import and reading

Tags: java, dictionary, ascii, bufferedreader

I am making a game in Java, and I want the player to be able to move in a world, with specified borders.

After searching the web for ways to define a 'world', in other words where the player can move, and where not.

I like the idea of 2D ASCII maps, where one character represents a certain amount of pixels, for example:

```
###################
#-----------------#
#-----###---------#
#-----###---------#
#-----------------#
###################
```

In this example, the `-` character represents a 10x10 tile where the player is allow to move in, and the `#` character represents a 10x10 area where the player can't come.

In Java, I import the `world.txt` using:

```
void importMap() {
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("world.txt"));
  String line;
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     for (char ch: line.toCharArray()) {
       // Add to array
     }
  }
  br.close();
}
```

However, I have no idea where to store this data. I'm thinking of a 2D array to that I can simply get the character at a certain x,y value like this:

```
world[7][3];
// Should return #
```

**How should I store this ASCII map? A 2D array, a 2D object, a hashmap, etc. ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 2d array would be best since it carries the smallest memory footprint, and you'll be doing mostly direct accesses. A hashmap carries space overhead and really doesn't add anything useful. As @assylias mentioned, abstracting the data structure in a class makes for a clean interface. @Alexander Tokarev is right about not knowing the array dimensions up front, but you can get around that using NIO.

```
char[][] createWorld(String file)
{
    try {
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(file),
            Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
        char[][] world = new char[lines.size()][];
        int i = 0;
        for(String ln: lines)
            world[i++] = ln.toCharArray();
        return world;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getGlobal().log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Storing the info in a 2D array seems a reasonable solution. However you would probably benefit from hiding that inside a class, for example:

```
class WorldMap {
    private final char[7][3] world = new char[7][3];

    //x,y below are pixels, so you don't need to convert from array index to pixels
    //everywhere in your code
    public boolean canMoveTo(int x, int y) { ... }

    public void addObstacle (Rectangle r) { ... }
}
```

you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

The main drawback of storing the data in a 2D array is that you should know the size of your "World" before parsing to create a suitable array. If the size is constant - then 2D array will fit your solution. If not - consider using different structures.

You can also create some dynamically expanded structure, like ArrayList, and transform it to 2D array after parsing. This will solve an unknown size issue.

Comment: A dynamic 2D array class (maybe implemented using ArrayList of ArrayList) would be cool.